# C# Split Regex: Capture a group when follow by characters

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a string:
`LRS00969`

I want to split on 0s, but only if the group is preceded by non-number. I also want to preserve 0s in the returned array.

So far I've got to this: `[A-Z](0{1,})`

However, when I split using Regex in ASP.NET, it returns `string[] { "LRS969" }`. I would like it to return `string[] { "LRS", "00", "969" }`. If I use `(0{1,})` instead, it splits correctly, but of course it will match strings where 0s follow other numbers as well ( such as `LRS100969` )

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `(?<=[^0-9])(0+)`. If I understand it right, you are using `Regex.Split`.

Comment: @ClasG didn't work, still returns LRS969

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yap that did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<=[^0-9])(0+)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5B%5E0-9%5D%29%280%2B%29&i=LRS00969)

**Details**:

- `(?<=[^0-9])` - a positive lookbehind that requires a character other than a digit immediately to the left of the current location
- `(0+)` - matches *and captures* into Group 1 (so that `Regex.Split` could paste this value into the resulting array) one or more `0` characters.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me why (?<=[^0-9])(0+) works, but (?<=[^0-9])(0{2,}) emits 0s group from results in c# split?

Comment: Yes you're right, I lost (..) around 0{2,} during testing just now. Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. You need to wrap those parts of the pattern you need to get as parts of the resulting array with capturing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that works in other environments as well would be

```
(?<!\d)(?=0)|(?<=0)(?!0)
```

matching the boundary between a "non-number" and a `0`, **or**, the boundary after last `0` in a sequence (that could be only one long).

Since it's only look-arounds, no actual characters are matched, and thus it works without the "re-insert-delimiter" feature ;)

[See it here at REGEXSTORM.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%28%3F%3D0%29%7C%28%3F%3C%3D0%29%28%3F!0%29&i=LRS00969)

[and here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nOOvCd/2/).